# XAMPP Server is not Starting in Port 80

Tags: port, http, xampp

I am using `XAMPP Control Panel V3.2.1` I have configured port no `80`

When I press Start I am getting Error like below

[image]

I used below cmd in command prompt for which services is running in port 80

```
net stop http
```

the Result is

```
The HTTP Services is not started
```

**EDIT**:

Starting Apache from a command line, it shows this:
[image: Apache]

Comment: Try starting apache from a CLI, this will output an error hopefully.

Comment: If you are on windows start a `Windows Command Prompt`, on Linux or Mac start `Terminal`. Then `cd` into your xampp folder and start apache by issuing `httpd` or similar.

Comment: even I changed the port no `1234` in `httpd.conf`. it shows same error.

Comment: Thatswhy you should start pache from console and see if it shows some errors from there. Otherwise it is wild guessing.

Comment: There you go: `Syntax error on line 51`. Open the file `C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` with a text editor and check what's wrong on line 51.

Comment: Thanks @duenni it resolved ;). It is my mistake. The Virtual host is not connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the error log is empty you could try and start XAMPP/Apache from a command line/console window.

In your case there is a `Syntax error on line 51`. Open the file `C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` with a text editor and check what's wrong on line 51.